# Solve a transaction with mongodb (waterline.js) and node.js (sails.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, transactions, sails.js

Given is this situation:

-**UserA** publishs a **Campaign** with a given **amount** of photo uploads.

-other **Users** can upload **Photos**

-**UserA** can **accept** the uploaded **Photos**

-the owner of the photos get for each accepted photo 1 **Coin**

-for each accepted photo the amount of possible photos in the campaign decrease.

I solved the "accept photos" function like this (pseudocode):

```
accept: function (req, res, next) {

        var photos = req.param('photos'); // [1, 2, 5]
        var campaign_id = req.param('campaign_id'); //1

        Photo.update(photos, {status:'accepted'}).exec(function afterwards(err, updatedPhotos) 
            {
                     //get the users Ids from the updatedPhotos
                      // also know how many photos of each user were accepted

                      User.update(users){
                         //increase the amount of coins of this user 
                       }

                      Campaign.update(amountOfAcceptedPhotos){
                         //decrease the amount of selectable photos. 
                       }

            })

}
```

Everything worked well first, til I noticed when you send quickly the same request with the same photoID's, the Users will get for the same photo multiple coins! How can I prevent this?

Here is a Link for the whole Code, if you want to see the exact function:
https://jsfiddle.net/zsmuoh0x/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that implements the two phase commit system described in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#transaction-like-semantics). It might help in this scenario. [Fawn - Transactions for MongoDB](https://github.com/e-oj/Fawn). Example: Transferring $20 from one bank account to another

```
var Fawn = require("Fawn");

// intitialize Fawn
Fawn.init("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testDB");

/**
optionally, you could initialize Fawn with mongoose

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testDB");
Fawn.init(mongoose);
**/

// after initialization, create a task
var task = Fawn.Task();

// assuming "Accounts" is the Accounts collection
task.update("Accounts", {_id: "Sender"}, {$inc: {balance: -20}})
  .update("Accounts", {_id: "Reciever"}, {$inc: {balance: 20}})
  .run()
  .then(function(results){
    // task is complete 

    // result from first operation
    var firstUpdateResult = results[0];

    // result from second operation
    var secondUpdateResult = results[1];
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    // Everything has been rolled back.

    // log the error which caused the failure
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Maybe include some detail from your links, so that future users can find info - even if the links go dead.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, I guess you are storing the user selected photos somewhere at campaigns collection for example:

```
{Id:999, Name: mycampaign, photos:[1,7] }
```

So, the update query should select the document by id AND by photo id. If you want to add picture 3:

```
db.campaigns.update({id:999, photos:3},. {$addToSet:{photos:3}})
```

If result of that is 1 documents updated, then increment the user coins.

PS: I am answering via a mobile phone